# -bash: opt: command not found in MAC OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, bash, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-gcc

I am trying to run a LLVM pass and have the following version of gcc:

Configured with:

```
-- prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

I downloaded the LLVM 3.2 source from the official site and have that unzipped in my project folder.

From the project folder I am trying to run the following command:

```
opt -load /Users/jigs/Downloads/CS_298/llvm-3.1.src/lib/Transforms/LLVMHello.dylib -hello -S morph_1.s mul -o=morph_output.s
```

I get an error saying opt does not exist. I am pretty sure opt is a part of LLVM source but it does not work.

Comment: Maybe try using `./opt -load ...`

Comment: Hi, is still gives the same error :
-bash: ./opt: No such file or directory

Comment: Is the `opt` command in the project directory? You need to call it from wherever it's at. Try doing `ls | grep opt` to check if it's there.

Comment: Hi, the opt command is in the llvm-3.1.src/tools folder. Still not able to run it.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the official site"*? The best, current, and only way to install Apple compiler and development suite, AFAIK, is to go to the `App Store` and download `Xcode` and then do `xcode-select --install`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: OP is trying to use the `opt` command, which isn't part of the standard Apple tools.

Comment: @ l'L'l , even if i run the command from the tools path, it does not find the opt and gives the error.
@Mark We can also get the command line tools directly without downloading the Xcode.

Comment: @Austin: Are you including the `./` (period and forward slash) in front of the cmd? Try going into the directory with the opt tool and do `./opt` all by itself — see if that does anything.

Comment: @I'L'I it still gives me the same error even after including the ./ in front of cmd.

Answer (score 2):

The `opt` tool should appear in the `bin` directory after building *(yours will be version 3.x.x)*, so I believe you are looking in the wrong place altogether. The `opt` in tools is a directory, so that's certainly not going to do much for you.

```
/llvm-3.7.0.src/build/bin

$ ./opt -version

LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 3.7.0
  DEBUG build with assertions.
  Built Sep  8 2015 (17:54:06).
  Default target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
  Host CPU: ivybridge
```

If you don't have a `bin` directory present after compiling/building from source then something likely isn't correct within your `makefile` perhaps.

**TIP**: Often you can tell where the executables are that were built by looking at the most recently modified directory within the source tree. Also, I think the easiest and most hassle free way to build `LLVM` from source is to use `CMake` — it conveniently includes a `CMakeLists.txt` config.

Comment: Hi I'L'I, it worked for me,
I checked in the Debug+Asserts/bin/opt path and it the opt version command works from there.
But somehow when i run the following command:
./opt -load /Users/jigs/Downloads/CS_298/llvm/Debug+Asserts/lib/LLVMHello.dylib -hello -S morph_1.s mul -o=morph_output.s
i get the error as :
opt: Too many positional arguments specified!
Can specify at most 1 positional arguments: See: ./opt -help

Comment: @Austin: Glad you finally found the command. The error is unrelated to this question, so post another question regarding that. Please mark this answer correct if it helped you, cheers!